# How to bind Two modal as 1 ViewModel in Angular 8

Tags: angular, data-binding

I want to bind `ViewModel` in `Angular 8` `Component` name "Test". I initialize the `Viewmodel` as `null`. It works fine with model but not with `ViewModel`.
here is link Code editor link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a95o1e

**Model # 1**

```
export class GoldDetail
{
     //For Gold 
    GoldDetailId: number;
    PurchaseNo: number;
    SaleNo: number;
    Weight: number;
}
```

**Model # 2**

```
export class CurrencyDetail {

    Name :string;
    CurrencyId:number;
    Amount:number;
```

}

**i add view model like this**

```
export class Vmmodel
{
  goldDetail :GoldDetail;
  currencyDetail:CurrencyDetail;
}
```

i want to bind this "**VmModel**" to in my component.
i initialize viewmodel with null.eg
**test.ts**

```
  resetForm(form? : NgForm): any {
        if(form!=null)
          form.reset();
          this.paymentService.vmmodel ={
           currencyDetail:new  CurrencyDetail(),
           goldDetail:new GoldDetail(),

      }
  }
```

**test.html**

```
<form   autocomplete="off"  #golddetail="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(golddetail)" >

    <div class="form-group col" >
        <label>weight</label>
    <input #currencyDetail.Name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="paymentService.vmmodel.currencyDetail.Name" class="form-control">

      </div>
</form>
```

but i got error in console . see attachment [pelase see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLdDW.png.)

Thanks in advance i try my best to explain my prblem.

Comment: If you can you should create a jsfiddle or some sort of solution we can test against.

Comment: check this. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a95o1e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of convention problems here, but let's stick on the main question.

You are using `vmmodel` before it is initialized.

```
<input #currencyDetail.Name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="paymentService.vmmodel.currencyDetail.Name" class="form-control">
```

Only on reset you do initialize a value to it. What your code is trying to do is access `paymentService.vmmodel.currencyDetail.Name`. In other word it cannot read the value of `...vmmodel.currencyDetail` because vmmodel is `undefined`.

> [Read on the difference between null and undefined](https://codeburst.io/javascript-null-vs-undefined-20f955215a2).

When the form is "created", the `input` is filled with whatever value there is in the `ngModel`.

You could intilialize the variable with default values or use the coalease operator.

Noneless you should create a minimal reproductible of your problem so we can start from somewhere.

### EDIT

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  vmmodel = new Vmmodel(); // as simple as that. This is still going to have problems as inner properties are not initialized neither and paymentService is undefined as well.

  resetForm(form? : NgForm): any {
    if(form!=null)
      form.reset();
    this.vmmodel ={
     currencyDetail:new  CurrencyDetail(),
     goldDetail:new GoldDetail(),
      // AcBankAccountHolders:null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Igor you are right, but I'm trying to make the problem more understandable. **EDIT** I updated my answer with a link between the difference. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: so what show id do now?
i want to save data using viewmodel. 
who is possible according to yours

Comment: how i initialize vmmodel ??

Comment: @FaizanHazma <strike>Can you provide your `Component` class code?</strike> I just saw your comment

Comment: export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public paymentService:PaymentService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.paymentService.allPaymentsArray;
  }
  resetForm(form? : NgForm): any {
    if(form!=null)
      form.reset();
      this.paymentService.vmmodel = new  Vmmodel();
      this.paymentService.vmmodel =null;
  }
}

Comment: @FaizanHazma I just saw that you are trying to access `vmmodel` from `paymentService` which don't exist as of current state...

Comment: yes you right it comes form PaymentService. for the time being i did not show payment serives.

Comment: Soved..!!
Thanks Man

Comment: @FaizanHazma Glad I could help. Please if this answer help you solve your problem mark it as the good answer. It helps other know that this solution helped you solved the problem

Comment: @FaizanHazma The small checkmark under the arrows on the top left of the answer.